# UITableView Batch Updates: `reloadRows` reloads wrong cell when used in conjunction with `moveRow`

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am having some real problems batch updating/animating UITableViewCell's.

I am unable to get a cell to reload when another cell moves before it.

Not sure if I am doing something wrong or whether there's a legit bug in UITableView.

### Example

Given a starting set of cell data ordered as follows...

```
anna [19]
bob [16]
chloe [13]
```

when updating the cell data to...

```
bob [17]
chloe [13]
anna [19]
```

... and attemping to animate the change in a batch with (psuedo code)...

```
moveRow(at: 0, to: 2)   // to move "anna" from first to last position
reloadRows(at: [1])     // to reload "bob" since its number changed from 16 to 17
```

... the wrong cell is reloaded and I end up with...

```
chloe [13]
chloe [13]
anna [19]
```

### Resulting Animation

[image]

### Sample Code

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    private var data: [String] = [
        "anna [19]",
        "bob [16]",
        "chloe [13]",
    ]

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {

            print("---- PERFORMING BATCH UPDATES ----")

            self.data = [
                "bob [17]",  // this row has had its value updated
                "chloe [13]",
                "anna [19]", // this row has moved from its previous position of index 0
            ]

            self.tableView.performBatchUpdates({

                // Reload "bob" row
                let reloadIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)
                self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [reloadIndexPath], with: .automatic)

                // Move "anna" row from index 0 to index 2
                let fromIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
                let toIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)
                self.tableView.moveRow(at: fromIndexPath, to: toIndexPath)

            })
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let value = data[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = value
        print("DRAWING cell at indexPath: \(indexPath), value: \(value)")
        return cell
    }
}
```

### Resulting Console Output

```
DRAWING cell at indexPath: [0, 0], value: anna [19]
DRAWING cell at indexPath: [0, 1], value: bob [16]
DRAWING cell at indexPath: [0, 2], value: chloe [13]
---- PERFORMING BATCH UPDATES ----
DRAWING cell at indexPath: [0, 1], value: chloe [13]
```

### What This Issue IS NOT

- I AM aware that there are limitations with batch updates and that it is not possible to move and reload the *same* cell in the same batchwithout getting a `attempt to perform a delete and a move from the same index path` crash  (references [here](https://www.matrixprojects.net/p/uitableview-moves-and-updates/) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084087/how-to-reload-programmatically-moved-row))
- HOWEVER that is NOT what is happening here. This issue moves one cell
  and reloads another (which is not explicily moved).
- For the `reloadRows` call I am deliberate using index 1, the cells original position, rather than 0, its final position, because thats exactly what the [offical Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows) demands.  This is further backed up by the fact that calling `reloadRows` with index 0 instead results in the `attempt to perform a delete and a move from the same index path` crash.

### Some Addtional Notes

- You can see from the console log that `tableView(_:,cellForRowAt:)` is invoked as part of the update but it is reloading the wrong cell
- Swapping the order of the `moveRow` and `reloadRows` calls makes no difference
- Using `beingUpdates()`/`endUpdates` as opposed to `performBatchUpdates` makes no difference

### Please Help!

---

### DifferenceKit

The bug even seems to occur with DifferenceKit.  I updated their demo app to simulate the same situation and this is the resulting animation.

[image]

The code with the problem is available here...

https://github.com/OliverPearmain/DifferenceKit/tree/reload-with-move-bug

And I've raised an issue with DifferenceKit here...

https://github.com/ra1028/DifferenceKit/issues/98

Comment: If the deployment target can be iOS 13+ I'd suggest `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` otherwise [DifferenceKit](https://github.com/ra1028/DifferenceKit). Both APIs handle those changes in a smart and fast way.

Comment: Deployment target is iOS 11.  DifferenceKit also seems to suffer from this same issue on occasion...

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform `batchUpdates` with this one.

The reason is because when you do `batchUpdates`, `UITableView` will do all the changes at the same time. This caused a crash with error

```
attempt to perform a delete and a move from the same index path
```

This crash occur because when the `UITableView` move anna cell to the bottom, it will not move bob cell to the top until all update is performed (hence called `batchUpdates`).

When `UITableView` try to reload cell at `IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)`, it crashed.

**Solution:**

Don't perform batch update. Just move anna cell to the bottom first, and then perform reload on bob cell.

```
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
        self.dataSource = [
            "bob [17]",
            "chloe [13]",
            "anna [19]"
        ]

        self.tableView.moveRow(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), to: IndexPath(item: 2, section: 0))
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    }
```

For more information:

- [performBatchUpdates on table view](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/2887515-performbatchupdates)

*note*

`beginUpdates` will be deprecated in a future release, the replacement is `performBatchUpdates`

```
// Use -performBatchUpdates:completion: instead of these methods, which will be deprecated in a future release.
open func beginUpdates()
```

Comment: Perhaps you missed the the notes I made...
"For the reloadRows call I am deliberate using index 1, the cells original position, rather than 0, its final position, because thats what the documentation suggests."