# How to move and reload UITableView row within same beginUpdates / endUpdates operation?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working on quite complex updates on a UITableView. Multiple rows can be **moved**, **deleted**, **inserted** and **changed** at the same time. What is the correct way to handle these changes within the same `tableView.beginUpdates()`/ `tableView.endUpdates()`block?

Example:

```
Data before update  ==>  Data after update
==================       =================
0: zero                  0: zero
1: one                   1: 555 (updated element five)
2: two                   2: three
3: three                 3: 222 (updated element two)
4: four
5: five

==> Elements 1 and 4 are deleted
==> Elements 2 and 5 are updated (content changes) and they switch their position
```

This can be done using a simple ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton!
    
    var rowTitles = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return rowTitles.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = rowTitles[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    
    @IBAction  func click() {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        
        // "zero", "one", "555", "three", "four", "222"
        rowTitles[2] = "555"
        rowTitles[5] = "222"
        
        // "zero", "555", "three", "four", "222"
        rowTitles.remove(at: 1)
        
        // "zero", "555", "three", "222"
        rowTitles.remove(at: 3)
        
        
        // Delete "one" (original index = 1)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        
        // Delete "four" (original index = 4)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 4, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        
        // Move "two" and "five", use new old index for source and new index for destination
        tableView.moveRow(at: IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0), to: IndexPath(row: 3, section: 0))
        tableView.moveRow(at: IndexPath(row: 5, section: 0), to: IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0))
        
        // CRASH
        //tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 5, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, except moving and reloading the rows 2 and 5 at the same time. I `reloadRows(...)` is not used, the code runs but results in a list `zero, five, three, two`. So, the elements in the correct order, but the rows have not been updated to `555` and `222`.

When using `reloadRows(...)` with the original indexes 2 and 5 the app crashes because move+delete have been called for the same indexes (it seems that reload is internally handled as delete+add).

Using `reloadRows(...)` AFTER `endUpdates()` delivers the correct result. However, I wonder if this is the correct way to go. Regarding the Apple Docs `reloadRows(...)` should be called within `beginUpdates ... endUpdates`.

**So, what is the correct way to solve this?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084087/how-to-reload-programmatically-moved-row

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what visual effect you're going for, but...

You probably want to reload the table view and *then* remove / rearrange the rows.

Try it like this:

```
@IBAction  func click() {

    rowTitles[5] = "555"
    rowTitles[2] = "222"
    
    let p1 = IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)
    let p2 = IndexPath(row: 5, section: 0)
    self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [p1, p2], with: .automatic)
    
    rowTitles.remove(at: 1)
    rowTitles.remove(at: 3)

    // need to update order in array
    rowTitles[1] = "555"
    rowTitles[3] = "222"
    
    tableView.performBatchUpdates({

        // Delete "one" (original index = 1)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        
        // Delete "four" (original index = 4)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 4, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        
        // Move "two" and "five", use new old index for source and new index for destination
        tableView.moveRow(at: IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0), to: IndexPath(row: 3, section: 0))
        tableView.moveRow(at: IndexPath(row: 5, section: 0), to: IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0))

    }, completion: { _ in
        // if you want to do something on completion...
    })

}
```

End result order is:

```
zero
555
three
222
```